# What kind of differential equation is $(x^2+2y^3)y'=xy$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

what kind of differential equation is $(x^2+2y^3)y'=xy$?, I think its an inexact differential first order, its surely not linear, I tried to check if its separable also didn't work, its not also homogeneous. and I thought about a way of solving the equation by saying that $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{x}{y} + \frac{2y^2}{x} $ , and I succeeded at finding $u(y)$ at this case but got stuck at calculating: $\int \frac{2y}{x} $ at some point, does it have to be according to  $y$ or $x$?, I would be glad for some clarifications.

Comment: Indeed, not linear, not separable. I think that if you want to solve this differential equation, you should do some clever substitution. That is, introduce a new function $z(x)$ in terms of $x$ and $y(x)$. At the moment, I don't see how this should be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you are on the right way, writing
$$
\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{x}{y}+\frac{2y^2}{x}.
$$
Let us view $x$ as a function of $y$, and introduce $z(y)=\frac{x(y)}{y}$. Then $x=yz$, so $\frac{dx}{dy}=z+y\frac{dz}{dy}$. Let us now replace all instances of $x$ and of $\frac{dx}{dy}$ in the differential equation, and simplify. Unless, I did something wrong, we end up with
$$
z\frac{dz}{dy}=2.
$$
Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Im not sure I quiet understood how u got to the last line?

Comment: I updated with some more details. I want you to work as much as possible, so I don't give it all away directly...